# How to trigger an email on field change

Tags: python, django

I have a contact form that users can use to send complaints. However, I want a situation where the support team can indicate if a complaint is resolved or not and it will trigger an email when the status change to 'Resolved'. By default, the complaint is 'pending'. I am currently using a signal.

Please, can someone help me because it's not sending email when the status change to 'Resolves'. what am I not doing right?

This is what I did:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Contact)
def send_email_on_status_change(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # Check if the field that you want to watch has changed
    if instance.status == 'Resolved':
        # Construct and send the email
        subject = "Contact status changed"
        message = "the status of this complaint has changed to has changed to '{}'".format(instance)
        send_mail(
            subject,
            message,
            'sender@example.com',
            ['recipient@example.com'],
            fail_silently=False,
        )
    
    @receiver(pre_save, sender=Contact)
    def save_status(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.status.save()@receiver(pre_save, sender=Contact)
def send_email_on_status_change(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # Check if the field that you want to watch has changed
    if instance.status == 'Resolved':
        # Construct and send the email
        subject = "Contact status changed"
        message = "the status of this complaint has changed to has changed to '{}'".format(instance)
        send_mail(
            subject,
            message,
            'sender@example.com',
            ['recipient@example.com'],
            fail_silently=False,
        )
```

**Model**

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICE = (
        ("1", "Pending"),
        ("2", "Resolved"),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_CHOICE, default="Pending", max_length=50)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    body = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-created"]
        verbose_name_plural = "Contacts"

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Message from: {self.name}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first value is saved in database, so you need to check with that value. Repace 'Resolved' with '2'

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Contact)
def send_email_on_status_change(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # Check if the field that you want to watch has changed
    if instance.status == '2':
        # Construct and send the email
        subject = "Contact status changed"
        message = "the status of this complaint has changed to has changed to '{}'".format(instance)
        send_mail(
            subject,
            message,
            'sender@example.com',
            ['recipient@example.com'],
            fail_silently=False,
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using post_save instead of pre_save. Post_save will trigger when the data has been committed with save(), So at that instance the status will have been set to resolved.

Also check if the signals has been registered in your app.

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'my_app'

    def ready(self):
        import my_app.signals
```

Comment: I have done that but still not sending the emails. I have updated my question to include the model maybe there is something I am not doing right.

Comment: Have you imported your signals file in app.py file like below ??

Check the actual answer which has been edited with code.